# Copying complex large text from word takes time

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have 5 paged Word doc. It has pages in landscape mode and has two column format. Also, it contains some tables, diagrams and equation inside and outside table. I wanted to copy the content of that file to another. However, when I select all text (Ctrl+A) and do copy (Ctrl+C), it takes a lot of time to end that copying process. Word becomes unresponsive. After some 4-5 minutes, it succeeds in copying that content to clipboard which I can then paste in another document. Sometimes pasting also takes considerable time. Is this normal when copying complex large text? Can I speed up this in any way?

Environment:
Word 2016
Windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: What OS? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Windows 10, 64 bit, Office 2016

Comment: *Is this normal when copying complex large text?* Yes. But the reason it that the text is not large but complex. Store your source file onto the disk and use "Insert - From file" command.